# How do I set environment variable in Meteor's provided server?

Tags: meteor

I'd like to test meteor google analytics package on a remote server.

**settings.json**

```
{
  "public" : {
    "ga": {
      "account":"UA-dfgddhdh-5"
    }
  }
}
```

In a local server, I just pass in `--settings` option. I looked at http://meteorpedia.com/read/Environment_Variables and http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/meteor_settings but it's still unclear what I should do to set this environment variable inside `meteor deploy`. Thank you for your help!

EDIT:

```
if (Meteor.isServer) {
  Meteor.startup(function () {
    var settings = JSON.parse(
      '{"public" : {"ga": {"account":"UA-5555555-5"}}}'
    );
    process.env.METEOR_SETTINGS = settings;
  });
}
```

Is this the right approach? Also, https://github.com/datariot/meteor-ganalytics package requires this setting before the package itself is loaded. How do I ensure it?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use, on the server side:

```
process.env.ENV_VARIABLE = "something"
```

instead of `$ export ENV_VARIABLE='something'`

Comment: Thank you! could you see the edited question for me?

Comment: @MaximusS You could do it but its not the best approach. When running `meteor deploy`, simply add `--setings /path/to/settings.json` to it instead. Unrelated but the JSON needs to be raw you need not run parse

Comment: @akshat is right. You do it the same as you would locally by adding - -settings

Comment: @MaximusS but you use "--settings " if you doing "meteor build" as node