# Property 'MAIL_URL' does not exist on type 'ProcessEnv'

Tags: node.js, email, meteor, environment-variables

I'm using Meteor 1.6 and Node 9.2.0 and I want to send an email using the Email package but I get this error when I want to set the environment variable MAIL_URL
Property 'MAIL_URL' does not exist on type 'ProcessEnv'

```
Meteor.startup(() => {

    let smtp = {
        username: 'alaeddine.baghdadi1@gmail.com',
        password: '******',
        server: 'smtp.gmail.com',
        port: 465
    };



    process.env.MAIL_URL = 'smtp://' + encodeURIComponent(smtp.username) + ':' + encodeURIComponent(smtp.password) + '@' + encodeURIComponent(smtp.server) + ':' + smtp.port;
```

Thanks

Comment: Maybe set the environment variable in the environment instead of trying to monkeypatch it after Meteor has already started?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you should try with `process.env.MAIL_URL` instead of `ProcessEnv.MAIL_URL` ?

See [How do I set environment variable in Meteor's provided server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29574656/how-do-i-set-environment-variable-in-meteors-provided-server) for more information.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Meteor.startup(() => {

    let smtp = {
        username: 'alaeddine.baghdadi1@gmail.com',
        password: '********',
        server: 'smtp.gmail.com',
        port: 465
    };



    process.env.MAIL_URL = 'smtp://' + encodeURIComponent(smtp.username) + ':' + encodeURIComponent(smtp.password) + '@' + encodeURIComponent(smtp.server) + ':' + smtp.port;